# yfinance specific financials for multiple companies

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I want to get net income and research development for the current year from multiple companies. At present, ticker.financials from yfinance library gives me the full table for 4 years and for multiple metrics.

I am checking below the keys for financials and there are only by years.

```
# Import packages
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
info = msft.financials
info.keys()
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-06-30', '2020-06-30', '2019-06-30', '2018-06-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='', freq=None)
```

For example,

```
msft.financials
```

gives me this

[image]

I want to create a ticker group like

```
tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "IBM", "GOOG", "ORCL"]
```

For these companies I need the net income and research and development for 2021-06-30.

How is this possible with yfinance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the format in which the company's financial information is obtained is a data frame, the latest closing date is combined into an empty data frame. After merging, update the column names in the ticker list. The following is a part of the dataframe after the retrieval. With the obtained data, we extract the necessary subjects for each.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "IBM", "GOOG", "ORCL"]

df = pd.DataFrame()
cols = []
for ticker in tickers:
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    info = company.financials
    df = pd.concat([df, info.iloc[:,0]], axis=1)
    cols.append(ticker+'('+info.columns[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+')')
df.columns = cols

df.head()

    AAPL(2021-09-25)    MSFT(2021-06-30)    IBM(2020-12-31)     GOOG(2020-12-31)    ORCL(2021-05-31)
Research Development    21914000000.0   20716000000.0   6333000000.0    27573000000.0   6527000000.0
Effect Of Accounting Charges    None    None    None    None    None
Income Before Tax   109207000000.0  71102000000.0   4637000000.0    48082000000.0   12999000000.0
Minority Interest   None    None    129000000.0     None    714000000.0
Net Income  94680000000.0   61271000000.0   5590000000.0    40269000000.0   13746000000.0
```

**Research Development & Income**

```
df.iloc[[0,4],]
```

|  | AAPL(2021-09-25) | MSFT(2021-06-30) | IBM(2020-12-31) | GOOG(2020-12-31) | ORCL(2021-05-31) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Research Development | 2.1914e+10 | 2.0716e+10 | 6.333e+09 | 2.7573e+10 | 6.527e+09 |
| Net Income | 9.468e+10 | 6.1271e+10 | 5.59e+09 | 4.0269e+10 | 1.3746e+10 |

Comment: Thank you very much. I also checked in the above example msft.financials.loc['Net Income'] which appears to work and get just the Net Income. How would I get just the specific metrics instead of the big table? In this case it could be faster?

Comment: Simply put, I have determined that it is more advantageous in terms of speed to acquire the items that can be looped through and then extract the necessary subjects in post-processing. It is also possible to specify subjects in a separate loop. There is no reason why this method should not be used.

Comment: We decided that if we wanted to analyze other subjects, this approach would be better without having to reacquire them.